# nginx: Force browser to revalidate

Tags: nginx, browser-cache, cache-control

Below is my `nginx` server config. The `Cache-Control` header was recently added. My browser still has the old file cached and is NOT fetching it from the server - I verify this by tailing the `access.log`. Is there any way to force all users to fetch updated files from my server?

```
    location /webapp {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /webapp/index.html;
        add_header  Cache-Control must-revalidate always;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the file is cached, there is really not much you can do to invalidate the entry.

The user would generally have to issue a forced reload, which can often be accomplished by holding the SHIFT key together with pressing the RELOAD button.

Alternatively, if the resources at stake are loaded from within a webpage that you still do control, then you can often add a random string as an argument to the resource (e.g., replace `.png` in your webpage with `.png?v=$sha1`), which will often be ignored for static resources by nginx, yet will ensure that the resource has a new URL, and thus couldn't have been cached yet.  (The same trick, with adding a random noop parameter to the URL can also be used by the user to effectively force a new request regardless of whether the resource at stake might already have been cached.)

Comment: I thought so. Even though my url looks like this `https://host.com/webapp/unsubscribe/${hash1}/${hash2}?param=value` Chrome doesn't want to pick up the new index.html from the server. It shows a 200 OK for the request but nginx isn't logging anything in access.

Comment: @AnshulKoka, just add an extra `&20170714T1024PT` at the end of your URL (after `?param=value`), and see if that fixes it.  If not, then it's not an issue with browser caching, but is a backend issue unrelated to the browser.

Comment: Just did and no luck. FWIW, the `hash` fields are always unique too so the URL is unique which is what is baffling me as I still don't see anything in `access.log` besides a JS resource that the old `index.html` is trying to load and receiving back a `404` for it. Is there a way to catch this old resource and force the browser to reload instead of returning 404?

Comment: @AnshulKoka, then it obviously must not be a browser caching issue, and you're barking at the wrong tree!